# How to change semitransparent part

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, transparency

How do I make this picture white on transparent background and keep it's semitransparent parts -

[image]

(Background is already transparent).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a **Color Overlay Layer Style** and set that to white.

- Highlight the layer in the **Layers Panel**
- Choose `Layer > Layer Style > Color Overlay`
- Click the little color box in the Color Overlay dialog and set it to white
- Click OK

Comment: dude, I have no such submenu - `Layer Style` o_O. Google says that I have to install some plugins for it...

Comment: It's there in any standard installation of Photoshop since version 5.

Answer (score 1):

#### Gimp

- select *Color to Alpha* from the *Layer Transparency* or from the *Color* menu
- open the color picker by clicking on the color bar next to *From:*
- choose the appropriate color you want to transform to alpha

  [image]
  *Blue will make the background fully transparent, light-blue areas around the white element will be semi-transparent.*

  [image]
  *Dark red will make a semi-transparent blue background. But red elements in a picture will be made transparent too.*

The effect you want to achieve is a bit unclear, as the image you posted did not have any transparency.